# Facebook Graph API not working anymore. No changes made

Tags: facebook-graph-api

During the past couple of weeks I've been sporadically downloading posts from a couple of Facebook pages with this call:

`https://graph.facebook.com/105317422843784/posts`

Everything was working fine and I would get the usual json response of public posts (which doesn't require authentication afaik).

Now I get this:

> {
>      "error": {
>         "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 104
>      }
>   }

I haven't changed anything in my code, and I tested in two different browsers and two different machines with the same result. I don't think I've hit any limits (I'm using the API very seldom). I can't find any changes made to the API either.

Is anybody else having trouble with this? Can anybody point me to a lead?

Comment: This is also true of `https://graph.facebook.com/{albumId}/posts`, which I was using to grab photos from Facebook albums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From today, in order to get posts from public pages [through Facebook Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed), we always need to use [Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens).

**New Permissions**

> - An access token is required to view publicly shared posts.
> - A user access token is required to retrieve posts visible to that person.
> - A page access token is required to retrieve any other posts.

**Old Permissions**

> - An app or user access token is needed to view fields from fully public pages.
> - A user access token is needed to view fields from restricted pages that this person is able to view (such as those restrict to certain demographics like location or age, or those only viewable by Page admins).
> - A page access token can also be used to view those restricted fields.

Comment: Was this announced beforehand? If so where?

Comment: @xv70 I can't find any related announcements so far.

Comment: Well I can attest that many many apps broke as a result of this. :(

Answer (score 3):

Taken from the documentation on: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed/

```
An access token is required to view publicly shared posts.
A user access token is required to retrieve posts visible to that person.
A page access token is required to retrieve any other posts.
```

Looks like you need an access token.

Comment: additional info: if the page is restricted by age or location, you can´t use an app access token at all.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is going through an entire change with their recent conflicts and allegations. They have stopped all API pulling for now and the access will be given again once all your Facebook Developer apps are reviewed by them.